# angular 4 upload excel (xls,xlsx) and convert json record wise

Tags: excel, angular

i tried to convert excel to json using angular but its not working properly.
1. xls format file is converted json but i am getting tr td also included and i am unable to find the record individually .
2. xlsx format is not converting to json.

```
export class CustomQRComponent {
  // file: File;
  public fileString;
  public jsonvalue;

  constructor() {
    this.fileString;
  }
  fileEvent($event): void {
    this.readThis($event.target);
}

readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
  var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  var fileType = inputValue.parentElement.id;
  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    console.log(myReader.result);
    this.fileString = myReader.result; 
   // this.jsonvalue=JSON.parse(this.fileString)   
 };

  myReader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question. It is unclear what you did and what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a proper library to do that?
e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-to-json or somethign similar?

Also, if your excel is not formatting intense, can you export it as csv and then json may make things easier...
in your example you are assuming that  JSON.parse will take care of this for you but it may not in all cases.